# Why Windows XP machine is not accessible from Ubuntu machine?

Tags: php, apache-http-server, ubuntu

I am using Windows machine and using it as a sever which is properly accessible from my browser through url, but when I try to access windows directory from Ubuntu, I am not getting access to it.(Note:I have an admin privileged on Ubuntu).

What may be possible reason for this and how I access windows directory from Ubuntu?

Comment: you're in the wrong forum

Comment: What exactly do you mean by access it through your browser? Are you using it as a web server, file server? Can you access it on another Windows machine and what have you tried to resolve this problem so far?

Comment: Please be more verbose on your problem and in the meanwhile check if your firewall is blocking the server.